# Is there a way to stop Dropbox from opening Firefox as its default when viewing the Dropbox webpage?

Tags: 12.10, firefox, google-chrome, dropbox

I have Dropbox installed on my Ubuntu desktop 12.10, I also have Firefox and Chrome installed. Chrome is my default browser, I have checked in my mimeapps.list and its all correct. Yet for some reason the integration of Dropbox opens Firefox when I use the "Launch Dropbox website" option from the menu, is there a file somewhere this is looking at as I would like it to open in Chrome which I mostly have already running than launching a new instance of Firefox? 
Or could this be a Dropbox bug?

Comment: On my computer it opens in Chrome (set as default browser). What's your dropbox version? I have 1.6.16 under Ubuntu 12.10.

Comment: I am running 1.6.16 too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had similar problem with my Xubuntu 13.04 and I solve it with this commands.

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --config x-www-browser

  Selection    Path                Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/bin/opera              200       auto mode
* 1            /usr/bin/chromium-browser   40        manual mode
  2            /usr/bin/firefox            40        manual mode
  3            /usr/bin/opera              200       manual mode

Press enter to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

`x-www-browser` was set right because I want to use *chromium-browser* but problem was with next command where for `gnome-www-browser` was set opera.

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --config gnome-www-browser

    Selection    Path                Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/bin/opera              200       auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/chromium-browser   40        manual mode
  2            /usr/bin/firefox            40        manual mode
  3            /usr/bin/opera              200       manual mode

Press enter to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

So you just need to select the browser you want to use, in my case its *chromium-browser*, so I entered number `1` and it solve my problem with *Lunch Dropbox Website* in different browser.

Comment: It was indeed the 'gnome-www-browser' that was the problem, although for me it was set to use chrome, it was set to auto mode. So I changed it to open chrome in manual mode and this fixed the problem, thank you!

Comment: I use Lubuntu 12.04 and I changed both entries to chromium-browser manual mode, but still Dropbox (and its Nautilus integration) starts Firefox. I have Chromium set as preferred web browser in Lubuntu preferences.

Answer (score 3):

Dropbox is still a gtk2 application while Unity and current Gnome are on gtk3.
Gtk2 applications store their settings in gconf instead of dconf. Maybe they got out of sync.

Edit the following key:

```
/desktop/gnome/applications/browser/exec
```

with the gconf-editor user interface (available as package) or with gconf command:

```
gconftool -s /desktop/gnome/applications/browser/exec -t string google-chrome
```

Last not least there are the debian alternatives system, use package `galternatives` and change key `x-www-browser` to your liking.

Note that `google-chrome` is not the same as `chromium-browser`.

It is also possible that dropbox keeps the browser that it encountered during install, in this case please report the bug.

Comment: I followed your instructions but both keys are showing that google-chrome is the browser, so I am thinking this is a Dropbox bug after all. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

For me, none of ways to change default browser worked. It was probably Dropbox bug that was fixed in newer version.

Use solution from [Dropbox ignoring my default programs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/350667/dropbox-ignoring-my-default-programs)

If it does not work, you can try combining it with any of other answers.