# Dropbox ignoring my default programs

Tags: 13.04, dropbox

I'm currently using ubuntu 13.04. Dropbox, for some reason, is ignoring my default file manager and browser. Whenever I open the folder "Dropbox", it uses nautilus and not thunar (which is my default file manager.. Or so I thought?). On top of that, whenever I click on "Launch dropbox website", it does that by opening firefox, and not chromium (which is my default)

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening and how to fix it?

EDIT: It seems that every folder on my desktop is opening with Nautilus. I made Thunar my default application by going to exo-preferred-applications and choosing Thunar. Perhaps that's not enough?

Comment: I had same problem with default browser ignored by Dropbox and none solution worked. Some time ago it started to work on its own. Try to update Dropbox by using `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade` and see if it helps.

Comment: @Rafal Doing that fixed the browser issue. Sadly, I still have the file manager one.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know how to fix that bug with file manager as I use nautilus. Ps. I have added fix from comment as full answer as some people don't read comments.

Comment: Sure. I upvoted your comment. I'll not, however, accept the answer just yet, as it didn't fix the file manager issue. Ty tho!

Comment: Try to report bug to Dropbox. Maybe it is Dropbox itself source of the bug as with default browser.

Comment: Something weird is happening. Any folder on my desktop is opening with Nautilus. hum.. I chose thunar as my default application in exo-preferred-applications. Isn't that enough?

Answer (score 1):

Browser issue was obviously Dropbox bug, as updating Dropbox fixed that.

To update Dropbox enter:

`sudo apt-get update`

and then

`sudo apt-get upgrade`

This fixes not only "Launch dropbox website problem", but also sharing folders from file manager.

Comment: Actually, I just re-formated my PC. Dropbox had the same problem, tried those commands and puff... Still opening firefox. This is weird.